# Can XP user name be shortened without reinstall?

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

When I loaded Windows XP some years ago somehow ended up being too long.  It is often impossible to see the entire directory path.   How can I shorten the user name without reloading the OS?

Comment: What does a user name have to do with a path being too long?

Comment: The path is C:\Documents and Settings\ *User*

Answer (score 9):

Here's a guide that might help: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/userpath.htm

Comment: spot on       +1